# Concatenate a DataFrame column into a String

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame like below:

```
column_A   column_B
  2           4 
  7           1  
 Seven      Three
  34         23
```

I would like to return the values of column_A and column_B as a single string like below:

```
concatenated_A = 2, 7, Seven, 34
concatenated_B = 4, 1, Three, 23
```

I have tried to the below code:

```
concatenated_A = df[column_A].to_json()
print(concatenated_A)
```

But it is getting printed like below:

```
{"0":"2", "1":"7", "2":"Seven", "3":"34"}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`str.cat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.cat.html)

```
>>> df.column_A.str.cat(sep=' ')
'2 7 Seven 34'
```

Comment: Thank You. It worked for me. But prints all the int values as float like                           
    
    2.0 7.0 Seven 34.0.

Answer (score 1):

Get two columns output

```
df.apply(', '.join)
Out[41]: 
column_A    2, 7, Seven, 34
column_B    4, 1, Three, 23
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank You so much. This answer too worked for me. But accepting @RafaelC answer since it gives me the output that returns each column values separately.